# Как вывести значение из OpenWeather?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, openweathermap

```
 code_to_smail = {
        "Clear": 'Ясно\U00002600',
        "Clouds": 'Облачно\U00002601',
        "Rain": 'Дождь\U0001F327',
        "Thunderstorm": 'Гроза\U000026C8',
        "Mist": 'Туман\U0001F32B',
        "Snow": 'Снег\U00002744',
    }
```

Вот есть переменная code_to_smile там находятся погодные значения, я вставил снизу скриншот фотографии от сайта и нужно вывести Description. Как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хотите получать и использовать иконки в сообщениях, то в `JSON`, который отдает вам сервер, они есть и можно цепляться за них. Создайте словарь:

```
weather_icons = {
    '11d': '⛈',
    '09d': '',
    '10d': '',
    '13d': '❄️',
    '50d': '‍️',
    '01d': '☀️',
    '01n': '',
    '02d': '',
    '02n': '',
    '03d': '⛅️',
    '03n': '⛅️',
    '04d': '☁️',
    '04n': '☁️'
}
```

функцию для получения нужной иконки и температуры:

```
def get_weather():
    city_id = ''  # ID города
    key = ''  # Ваш API KEY
    weather_url = f'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id={city_id}&appid={key}&units=metric'
    weather = requests.get(weather_url).json()
    icon = weather_icons[weather['weather'][0]['icon']] if weather['weather'][0]['icon'] in weather_icons else ''
    weather_data = {
        'temp': weather['main']['temp'],
        'icon': icon
    }
    return weather_data
```

и используйте при отправке в сообщениях, например так:

```
await message.answer(f"В Москве сейчас {round(weather['temp'])}°C {weather['icon']}")
```

Comment: Мне просто смайлики нужно проставить, а если я просто из JSON все сделаю то это просто набор непонятных значений(точнее просто без смайликов, и иногда не понятно что вообще за погода), поэтому я хотел чутка добавить подробности для пользователя вместо к облачно добавить(переменная облачность и так далее) дождь (сильный или слабый).

Comment: @GuitarBattle исправил сообщение, посмотрите, возможно вариант с иконками вам подойдёт. Если вы все же хотите текстовое описание, то можно сделать по аналогии с иконками, только нужно будет предварительно переводить полученный description

Comment: Спасибо, именно то что мне нужно.